# Move elements from one place to another using XSLT 2

Tags: xslt-2.0

Move elements from one place to another using XSLT 2 (saxon8)

Hi all please help me to produce the following output using XSLT 2.0.

I have this:

```
<UL>
 <ITEM>
    aaa 
    <NL>iii
        <ITEM1>111</ITEM1>
        <ITEM2>222</ITEM2>
    </NL>
 </ITEM>
 <ITEM>
    bbb
    <NL>vvv
        <ITEM1>333</ITEM1>
        <ITEM2>444</ITEM2>
    </NL>
 </ITEM> 
</UL>
```

I need to produce this

```
<UL>
 <ITEM>
    aaa
    <ITEM1>111</ITEM1>
 </ITEM>
 <ITEM>
    bbb
    <ITEM1>333</ITEM1>
 </ITEM>
 <NEW>
  <NL>iii
   <ITEM2>222</ITEM2>
  </NL> 
  <NL>vvv
   <ITEM2>444</ITEM2>
  </NL>
 </NEW>
</UL>
```

I am trying to get the output using mode option as mentioned below:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="NL"/>
    <xsl:template match="ITEM2"/>

    <xsl:template match="UL">
      <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <NEW>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::NL" mode="move"/>
    </NEW>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ITEM" mode="move">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::ITEM2" mode="move1"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="NL" mode="move">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="ITEM2" mode="move1">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thanks and regards

Bala

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet that creates the structure you want, although white space is different, as it is a problem with mixed content to produce the exact output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="UL">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="ITEM" group-by="NL/*/node-name(.)">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="position() eq 1">
                        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                            <ITEM>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="text() | NL/*[node-name(.) eq current-grouping-key()]"/>
                            </ITEM>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <NEW>
                            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                                <NL>
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="NL/(text() | *[node-name(.) eq current-grouping-key()])"/>
                                </NL>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </NEW>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="NL/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I get the result

```
<UL><ITEM>
        aaa 
        <ITEM1>111</ITEM1>
    </ITEM><ITEM>
        bbb
        <ITEM1>333</ITEM1>
    </ITEM><NEW><NL>iii

            <ITEM2>222</ITEM2>
        </NL><NL>vvv

            <ITEM2>444</ITEM2>
        </NL></NEW></UL>
```

When I add instructions to strip white space from the input and indent the output, as in

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="UL">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="ITEM" group-by="NL/*/node-name(.)">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="position() eq 1">
                        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                            <ITEM>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="text() | NL/*[node-name(.) eq current-grouping-key()]"/>
                            </ITEM>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <NEW>
                            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                                <NL>
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="NL/(text() | *[node-name(.) eq current-grouping-key()])"/>
                                </NL>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </NEW>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="NL/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the result is

```
<UL>
   <ITEM>
        aaa 
        <ITEM1>111</ITEM1>
   </ITEM>
   <ITEM>
        bbb
        <ITEM1>333</ITEM1>
   </ITEM>
   <NEW>
      <NL>iii
            <ITEM2>222</ITEM2>
      </NL>
      <NL>vvv
            <ITEM2>444</ITEM2>
      </NL>
   </NEW>
</UL>
```

As an alternative, if we know there are just `ITEM1` and `ITEM2` we want to split, here is stylesheet using modes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="#all">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="#current"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="NL">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ITEM1"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ITEM2"/>

    <xsl:template match="UL">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            <NEW>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::NL" mode="move"/>
            </NEW>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ITEM1" mode="move"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Martin, Thanks for your reply, Is there any chance to use mode option to get the output? sample code mentioned above for your reference. mode1 not working.

Comment: @Bala, I have edited the answer and provided a sample using modes.

Comment: Thank you very much for your swift response. Please explain the mode options #all and #current.

Comment: If we want to use different modes but want to have the identity transformation template available in all modes we use then we put `mode="#all"` on the template and use `apply-templates mode="#current"` in the template to ensure the children and/or attributes are processed in the current mode, that is the mode the template has been applied with. That way, for the sample, we don't need to write a template for `ITEM2` elements to be copied in the mode `move`, the identity transformation template does that for us.

Comment: Why can't you use the identity transformation template? It is fundamental to most stylesheets, I don't see a reason not to use it.